# Order property in System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

If I have multiple authorization attributes on an action, my understanding is that for `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` I can specify the `Order` property like:

```
[CustomAuth(Order=2)]
[CustomAuth(Order=1)]
public ActionResult Get() { }
```

But this doesn't exist in the authorize attribute in the Web API. How do I order the execution of the attributes in the Web API?

Also, does the attribute at the class level always take precedence over the attribute that decorates the action?

Answer (score 3):

I can answer one of your questions.

> Also, does the attribute at the class level always take precedence
>   over the attribute that decorates the action?

ApiController.ExecuteAsync() runs the list of filters gotten from HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline(). Here is the comment given for GetFilterPipeline().

```
///Returns the filters for the given configuration and action. The filter
///collection is ordered according to the FilterScope (in order from
///least specific to most specific: First, Global, Controller, Action)
```

So, the gloabl filters run first, followed by controller level and then action level filters.

As far as your other question on how to order, I don't have a clear answer though. I understand the filters (attributes) are retrieved using Type.GetCustomAttributes(). This method does not guarantee any order but it usually returns in the reverse order. For example, if you have an action method like this,

```
[CustomAuth(Name="1")]
[CustomAuth(Name="2")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
}
```

the filter with Name="2" comes first in the list followed by "1" in the list returned by typeof(YourApiController).GetCustomAttributes(). If I were you, I'll not make any assumptions about this order. I'd much rather have one Authorization filter at the action method level and run the logic in the order I want it.

Anyways, if you add two global authz filters like

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuth() { Name = "g1" });
config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuth() { Name = "g2" });
```

and have a controller like

```
[CustomAuth(Name="c1")]
[CustomAuth(Name="c2")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [CustomAuth(Name="1")]
    [CustomAuth(Name="2")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
    }
}
```

the filters are run in this order: g1, g2, c2, c1, 2, and 1.